# OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ldap

I've configured OpenLDAP following the Ubuntu guide (with some minor edits, such as setting a proper password, my own domain name, and creating a staff group instead of an example one under people) through all steps except Replication.

Everything works just fine, except I can't use ldapscripts....

When I execute:

```
sudo ldapadduser gearge qa
```

I get an LDAP error, and the /var/log/ldapscripts.log states:

```
May 18 11:43:12 ubuntu ldapscripts: ldapadduser(khadri): /usr/sbin/ldapadduser george qa
No such object (32)
Matched DN: dc=khadri,dc=com
ldap_add: No such object (32)
    matched DN: dc=khadri,dc=com
  -> Error adding user george to LDAP
```

I'm pretty lost... I checked backend, frontend, /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd and the password matches...

My ldapscripts.conf file properly states:

```
# LDAP server
# DEBIAN: value from /etc/nslcd.conf (uri) is used.
SERVER="ldap://localhost"

# Suffixes
# DEBIAN: values from /etc/nslcd.conf (base maps) are used.
SUFFIX="dc=khadri,dc=com" # Global suffix
GSUFFIX="ou=Groups"        # Groups ou (just under $SUFFIX)
USUFFIX="ou=Peaple"         # Users ou (just under $SUFFIX)
MSUFFIX="ou=Machines"      # Machines ou (just under $SUFFIX)
```

Any ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in  ldapscripts.conf:

```
USUFFIX="ou=Peaple"         # Users ou (just under $SUFFIX)
```

should be

```
USUFFIX="ou=People"         # Users ou (just under $SUFFIX)
```